# Firebase Functions database trigger not firing

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying out Firebase Functions for the first time (Typescript). I have coded two functions:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
  const testRef = admin.database().ref("test");
  return testRef.set(true);
 });
export const testRef = functions.database.ref("test").onWrite((event) => {
    console.log("Event: " + JSON.stringify(event))
    const testRef = admin.database().ref("test");
    return testRef.set(true);
});
```

`helloWorld` works as expected when I navigate to the relevant URL. `testRef` on the other hand doesn't trigger when I insert or modify data at the "test" location in the root of the Firebase. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code itself looks fine. How do you change the database? If it is through code, show the code that modifies the database. If you do it manually through the Firebase console, show a screenshot or animation of what you do.

Comment: I add/modify the data in the console.

Comment: Here's a video: https://youtu.be/aVLxiKrqu3M

Comment: Note that when you do get the DB trigger to fire, the cloud function will run repeatedly.  Each time the function runs, the write to `admin.database().ref("test")` will cause the trigger to fire again.

Comment: Your cloud function should do as you expect. Mayb it was never triggered?
You can determine if the cloud function is triggered by looking at the functions list https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/PROJECT_ID/functions/list

Comment: @TroelsLenda, I'm having this issue too. I'm seeing my function in the functions list on the console/terminal while running it locally using the emulator but the function isn't getting triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The error I made was to expect to be able to execute the `database` function using `firebase serve`. It is possible to test the `http` function that  way which is why my `helloWorld` function was working. Testing `database` functions requires 'The Cloud Functions shell'.  [This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) (which I had failed to read thoroughly) describes how to test functions locally without deploying them.

Comment: @PeterHaddad I think you could do. The answer was a little off topic but your suggestion in the comment to redeploy did get me wondering whether I could test the function without deploying, so thanks for that.